# Using VBA in Excel to automatically update chart data

Tags: excel, vba

I currently am importing data into Excel. This data changes from time to time. I am trying to determine if there is a way to automatically update the data source range.

Comment: Yes there is. [Please see How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah, this is way too broad to even get started.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a name in the file with the data source range by going to Formulas -> Define Name. There you can set a name to be a formula that dynamically updates

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1))
```

This selects a table based on a count of how many values are in Column A and Row 1.